# Keras : Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,) - MNIST

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mnist

I'm trying to classify mnist's handwritten digits but I keep getting the same error from keras.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(15, input_shape=(784,), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

(data, label), (val_data, val_label) = mnist.load_data()


data = data.reshape(data.shape[0],data.shape[1]*data.shape[2])
val_data = val_data.reshape(val_data.shape[0],val_data.shape[1]*val_data.shape[2])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01),
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(data,label,batch_size=30,epochs=10,validation_data=(val_data,val_label))
```

Comment: I'm uncertain, but I think this is because you've specifed `loss='mse'`. Looks like you're trying to classify the mnist data. Can you try changing the loss to `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` ?

Answer (score 4):

The softmax layer expects a tensor of size (None, 10). So, you have to encode your label data using one hot encoder. It can be done in the following way:

```
label = keras.utils.to_categorical(label, num_classes = 10)
val_label = keras.utils.to_categorical(val_label, num_classes = 10)
```

If you are not familiar with one hot encoding, you can refer it here: [One hot encoding in python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/)